# Precompiled handlebars template. Cannot read property 'JST' of undefined

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, handlebars.js

I want to start off by saying that this is my first project using grunt and I apologize if I am missing something trivial. 
I am currently trying to cleanup my code and decided to move my handlebars templates out of my index.html file and into their own files. I also wanted to try precompiling these files. Since I was already using grunt, grunt-contrib-handlebars looked like the way to go.

Following instructions here: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-handlebars I installed grunt-contrib-handlebars using the following command:

```
npm install grunt-contrib-handlebars --save-dev
```

I also added the following code to my gruntfile:

```
...

    handlebars: {
        compile: {                                             
            files: {
                '<%= config.app %>/scripts/templates/handlebarTemplates.js': '<%= config.app %>/scripts/templates{,*/}*.hbs'
            }
        }   
    }
});

grunt.task.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-handlebars');

...
```

I currently compile the templates using:

```
grunt handlebars
```

This successfully generates the handlebarTemplates.js file. However, when I run the webpage I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'JST' of undefined
```

At line 1 in handlebarTemplates.js:

```
this["JST"] = this["JST"] || {};
```

Am I missing some initialization step?

I have not been able to find any discussion of this online so I assume I am missing something obvious. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

**Extra Info:**

I created my project / my gruntfile was generated using yeoman.

Please let me know if you need more code. I didn't want to overload my post with unnecessary code.

Comment: I got same error today when recompile templates, while it worked well until yesterday.